# Cómo solucionar Error running 'app': Default Activity not found

Tags: android, android-studio

Cuando intento correr mi aplicación aparece `Error running 'app': Default Activity not found`, sin embargo mi AndroidManifestx.ml creo que se encuentra bien ya que anteriormente no me ha dado problemas y no he realizado cambios en este archivo, simplemente de repente me salió el error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="io.github.ziceck.appgaci001">

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <application
        android:name=".Initializer"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:largeHeap="true">

        <activity android:name=".activities.HomeActivity">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
            android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.ProyectoActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.ProjectsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.ParticipantsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.ActivitiesActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.RepliesActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

También ya probé la opción de `File -> Invalidate Cache / Restart`, pero el eror persiste.

También intenté hacerlo desde `Run/Debug Configurations con Specified Activity` pero dice que la actividad no está declarada en el manifest, de hecho no reconoce ningún activity.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

build.gradle (Module: app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "io.github.ziceck.appgaci001"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "2018.12.05"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'net.gotev:uploadservice:3.4.2'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
}
```

build.gradle(Prohe)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: cual es la API que usas? has probado con otro dispositivo?

Comment: podes agregar los archivos de gradle? 'app' suele ser el modulo de de aplicacion.

Comment: y probá también con Build -> Clean Project

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez La mínima 19 y la máxima 27. No he probado en otro dispositivo.

Comment: @Juan,  el build.gradle(Module: app)?
No funcionó clean, igual ya había probado rebuild.

Comment: Si. Pero poné los dos en la pregunta. Tal vez algo esté mal configurado. Recordas haber renombrado el proyecto o algún cambio así?

Comment: tambien me paso y no encontre una repsuesta tecnica hasta que cambie de dispositivo

Comment: @Juan, ya los agregué.
No, de hecho ayer en la noche funcionaba y hoy que he vuelto a abrir el proyecto dejó de funcionar.

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez, pero después volvió a servir en el dispositivo en el que no servía?

Comment: si como te digo no encontre una respuesta tecnica

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En la configuración selecciona `Launch`: `Default Activity`, de esta forma tomará la configuración definida en el AndroidManifest.xml que en este caso sería abrir

```
<activity android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
    android:noHistory="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asegura volver a construir el proyecto

```
Clean Project > `Rebuild Project`
```

---

También puede funcionar invalidar el caché, ve a el menú de Android Studio:

`File` > `Invalidate Caches / Restart...`

Answer (score 2):

Me pasaba lo mismo y lo único que me funciono fue hacer lo siguiente:

```
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...
```

Comment: yes. just dit it. it worked !